# Migrating videosoft vsindextab from VB6 to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, windows-forms-designer, vb6-migration

I have a VB6 project I need to migrate to VB.NET.

I tryied with both the migrating tool of VB.NET express 2005 and 2008 with the same result.

When I try to open a form in designer mode containing a videosoft's vsindextab component in the resulting project of the migration, I receive the following error:

```
Warning 1   Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME)) C:\gestionbtdotnet\FormBT.Designer.vb   261 0
```

The line in error is in the designer.vb file and is the following:

```
CType(Me.vsIndexTab1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
```

(The vsIndexTab being a vsOcx6lib.vsindextab object)

I searched all over the web about it but couldn't find anything.

I tryied using a different .NET Framework version, I tryied copying the ocx file (vsocx6.ocx) to every possible places, I tryied simply erasing the line in error.

No luck.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can only migrate **code**. Projects that depend on third-party components that are **binary-only**  (like the `vsindextab`) will **not** migrate. You will have to find a replacement for the component, and re-write code to use the new component, or at least remove the component from any design time use and build custom `dllimport` code for use of the component at run time.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - that sounds like as good an answer as one could get for this question.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't solve his problem, and so I'm reluctant to add it to the answers space. Maybe if I could recommend a suitable .Net replacement it would make more sense.

Comment: Okay, I was able to improve the comment to present options. That's a better fit as an "answer" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can only migrate **code**. Projects that depend on third-party components that are binary-only and not .Net compatible (like the `vsindextab` component used here) will **not** migrate. Here are your options:

1. Check with the original vendor for a .Net version of the same component.
2. Find another .Net-compatible replacement for the component, and re-write code to use the new replacement.
3. Rewrite existing code to avoid using the component anywhere at design time. Factor that section out to it's own library that you can invoke at run-time only. Then build custom `dllimport` code to use that library at run time.
4. Write your own replacement for the component, relying on existing .Net widgets.